# FindWindow error 183

Tags: winapi, findwindow

Does anybody know what would cause the [`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to return the error:

> ALREADY_EXISTS error (183)

I could understand a `FILE_NOT_FOUND (2)`, but why would it return a `183`?

Comment: Are you sure that `FindWindow` is the one returning that error? Can you post some code to show us what you're doing?

Comment: FindWindow would never result in ALREADY_EXISTS. Nor will it result in a FILE_NOT_FOUND for that matter. Are you sure you are looking up a, euhmmm..., window? Aren't you looking for a file?

Comment: Can you share some code? Are you calling GetLastError after FindWindow, or taking to returned value to be error-code?

Comment: GetLastError returns the error value from the last winapi function that failed not from the last function that was called.
So you must only call GetLastError if FindWindow returnes NULL.

Comment: Just a "me too" comment: I'm getting the same error on _some_ systems, too for calling `FindWindow` on "Shell_TrayWnd" as the first parameter.

Answer (score 3):

MSDN says, that [`FindWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx)and [`FindWindowEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx) return NULL if the function fails and that you should check `GetLastError`. It seems that this documentation is wrong. Take this code fragment:

```
SetLastError(12345);
HWND h = FindWindow(L"class_name_that_does_not_exist", nullptr);
cout << h << ' ' << GetLastError() << endl;
```

It will output

> 00000000 12345

So as you can see `FindWindow` fails to set the last error. In your case this means that the `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` was the last error set before `FindWindow` was called.

Comment: Wouldn't say FindWindow fails to set the last error code. it's by design, it doesn't set the last error code

Comment: @Asesh Obviously you did not read the MSDN documentation (which I linked in my answer).