# Why does EnumWindows fail with ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

My program's call to [EnumWindows()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns FALSE and GetLastError() occasionally returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (#183, "Cannot create a file when that file already exists"). What does that error mean in that context?

Here is a code snippet:

```
static BOOL CALLBACK CollectTopLevelWindowsEnum(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // This one is good
    s_windows.push_back(hWnd);

    return TRUE;
}
```

...

```
if (!EnumWindows(CollectTopLevelWindowsEnum, NULL)) {
    DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
    if (lastError != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        TRACE("EnumWindows failed: %d.\n", lastError);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm puzzled. Isn't it the callback duty to `SetLastError` ? Could it be that the `push_back` operation throws and `return TRUE` is never reached ? What happes if you `SetLastError(0)` before `EnumWindows` ?

Comment: Tough one.  If this is a very occasional error then I'd guess at a race caused by a process creating a window while you are enumerating.  Here's somebody else with a very similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631089/findwindow-error-183

Comment: @ixe013 - push_back doesn't throw; if it did, the code would get an exception and not an error code. I'll try calling SetLastError(0) before EnumWindows and see if that helps, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Hans - The situation is very rare, but once it happens it continues to happen every time. I have seen EnumWindows fail several times per minute for over an hour (until the PC was rebooted). Not the usual signature of a race condition...

Comment: Next time it happens, start killing of processes one-by-one with Taskmgr.  With some luck you'll find the evil-doer.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?